# Error in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, operators

I'm getting an error on `else` saying:

> Syntax error on token "else", invalid OnlySynchronized

Why?

Here is the code:

```
if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))

    else(!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    {break;}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, that looks like *Java* which is most certainly not *Javascript*.

An *else* statement cannot have a condition clause, you must go directly to the curly braces. E.g.,

```
if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If you want a condition clause, you must use *else if*. E.g.,

```
if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
{
    ...
}
else if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```